# Python SQLITE3 Inserting Backwards

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a small piece of code which inserts some data into a database. However, the data is being inserting in a reverse order.
If i "commit" after the for loop has run through, it inserts backwards, if i "commit" as part of the for loop, it inserts in the correct order, however it is much slower.
How can i commit after the for loop but still retain the correct order?

```
import subprocess, sqlite3
output4 = subprocess.Popen(['laZagne.exe', 'all'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
lines4 = output4.splitlines()

conn = sqlite3.connect('DBNAME')
cur = conn.cursor()


for j in lines4:
    print j
    cur.execute('insert into Passwords (PassString) VALUES (?)',(j,))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Why does the order matter to you ?

Comment: what do you mean by backwards? How does the inserting order affect your database in any way? You could always reverse the lines4 list and then loop through it if you wanted to though.

Comment: Database tables are not ordered. You can ask for rows to be produced in a specific order with `ORDER BY`.

Comment: The order does matter in this instance. I am unsure as to why "committing" the database after every loop produces the correct output to "committing" after the for loop. Not sure why this was down voted...

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on *any* ordering in SQL database tables. Insertion takes place in an implementation-dependent manner, and where rows end up depends entirely on the storage implementation used and the data that is already there.

As such, no reversing takes place; if you are selecting data from the table again and these rows come back in a reverse order, then that's a coincidence and not a choice the database made.

If rows must come back in a specific order, use `ORDER BY` when selecting. You could order by `ROWID` for example, which *may* be increasing monotonically for new rows and thus give you an approximation for insertion order. See [*ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY*](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).